# How to use Turbolinks with AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, turbolinks

I'm working on a [angularjs](/questions/tagged/angularjs)project and I would like to add [turbolinks](/questions/tagged/turbolinks)to make the navigation on my WebSite **faster**. When I add [turbolinks](/questions/tagged/turbolinks)to my project, [angularjs](/questions/tagged/angularjs)is not working.

I did an example on Plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/S4AZXW6dQSahjHpAOdWQ?p=preview).

I have two pages, `index.html` and `products.html` that look like that:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.x" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.11/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.5.11"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <script src="turbolinks.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="products.html">Products</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
</body>

</html>
```

And a [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)file:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.products = 'Products';
});
```

You can see when [turbolinks](/questions/tagged/turbolinks)is added, the **`{{name}}`** and **`{{products}}`** values are not displayed.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: [**`Turbolinks`**](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks) performs a **`XMLHttpRequest`** request internally to load the content of the page without loading the `AngularJS` library or any `script` or `CSS` file. In Google Chrome, press F12 and see the network tab, compare its execution. 

 
I'd strongly recommend to see [**`ngView`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView) directive.

Comment: You seemed to be consumed with idea that turbolinks will be faster ... combining these frameworks doesn't make sense as mentioned yesterday. Use one or the other...combining them is not practical. Also doubt that you would see any significant difference